# Reseting the redux state of my app after leaving page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have seen similar questions, but none of them really apply.

All my app does, when the user clicks on one of the buttons, the action makes a get request and displays data from said request on the screen.
The problem is, after I leave the page, the displayed data stays. I would like that every time the user leaves the page, the data is gone (so only the default message is showing)

Here is my relevant code:

```
// the actions.js:
export function fetchLogs(logsUrl){
    const request = axios.get(logsUrl);
    return (dispatch)=>{
        request.then(({data}) => {
            dispatch({type: 'FETCH_LOGS',
                      payload: data,
                      url: logsUrl});
        });
    }
}

//reducer-logs.js
export default function (state=null, action){
    switch(action.type){
        case 'FETCH_LOGS':
            return {data: action.payload,
                    url: action.url};
        break;
    }
    return state;
}

//reducer's index.js
const allReducers = combineReducers({
    logs:Logs,
});

//log-directories.js (where the menu is with the possible options)
class LogList extends Component{
    render(){
        var me = this;

        return (
            <ListGroup>
                <ListGroupItem
                    bsStyle="success">{this.props.directory}</ListGroupItem>
                 {logList.map(function (log, key) {
                        return (<ListGroupItem
                            onClick={()=>me.props.fetchLogs(me.state.url+"/"+log)}>
                                {log}
                            </ListGroupItem>);
                    })}
            </ListGroup>
        );
    }
}

function mapStateToProps(state){
    return {
        logs: state.logs
    }
}

function matchDispatchToProps(dispatch){
    return bindActionCreators({fetchLogs: fetchLogs}, dispatch);
}

export default connect (mapStateToProps, matchDispatchToProps)(LogList);

//where the data from fetchLogs action is displayed: log-display-panel.js
class LogPanel extends Component{
    render(){
        if(!this.props.logs){
            return (<ListGroupItem bsStyle="warning">
                Please select a log from the list to view its content.
            </ListGroupItem>);
        }
        else{
            return (
          <Panel>{this.props.logs.data}</Panel>
            );
        }

    }
}

function mapStateToProps(state){
    return{
        logs: state.logs
    };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(LogPanel);
```

Comment: 'leave the page' as close the tab or change the route?. If that state only lives in that component, why bother putting it in redux

Comment: @xiaofan2406 I meant changing the route.
And I used Redux because it was the easiest way to get it done. I spent hours trying to use routes, and redux was just much much faster.

Comment: what I meant was: If you wish to reset the state of a component every time when the route changes, use component's internal `state`, in your case, you do not benefit from using `redux` at all

Answer (score 0):

You could either:

- Use React's local state for that particular component.
- In that component, use React's `componentWillUnmount()` lifecycle method to dispatch an action that triggers the reset on your Redux state.